# How could i add a peer in a running network of ethereum private network without stopping network and sync it with network also?

Tags: go-ethereum, network

I am running a private ethereum blockchain on 4 nodes which i am using as a static nodes but now when my network is running i want to add another peer in my network and sync that peer with my network also.How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

Run your new node with the same genesis file as the others then run geth and add the nodes using : admin.addpeer ()
E.g

```
admin.addPeer("enode://3414c01c19aa75a34f2dbd2f8d0898dc79d6b219ad77f8155abf1a287ce2ba60f14998a3a98c0cf14915eabfdacf914a92b27a01769de18fa2d049dbf4c17694@10.10.10.10:30301")
```

Comment: This is just for adding a peer but i want to add a peer without stopping my network and without any disturbance to other peers.

Comment: you add to your new nodes the existing nodes or some of them and don't forget to use the same genesis file

Comment: I know the new node must have the same genesis but how could i add a new node in running network of ethereum